# Ubuntu - Exclude certain IP's from being published in DNS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system

As the subject. I've joined my Ubuntu to an Active Directory domain, all is good except it's putting all its IP's in DNS and there's a few I don't want in there.

I only have the one i want publishing in `/etc/hosts` and not the other so I'm not sure how they're getting there?

The goal is to only have a single IP being published in DNS and i don't want to remove the other ones or put in a static entry - I just dont want them published in the first place.

Comment: You want to remove addresses from AD DNS or from Ubuntu files?

Comment: Ubuntu puts whatever IP addresses it has configured into DNS. The problem is, some of those addresses are only used locally (docker), I don't want these publishing to our DNS, i only want a particular IP being put in DNS

Comment: Can you show us the content of your _/etc/hosts_ file?

Comment: Thanks for the response Tom but the server was removed - unrelated to this.